# Electrical Project containing parts with different volts/amps rating

Tags: voltage, amperage, peltier, current-rating

So I have a small project just for fun.
Includes a Peltier module , and a small cooling fan like the ones used in a pc for airflow.

So my question is since the peltier module have a different rating than the fan. Is there any way to use just one power source? I tried it before by connecting the peltier and fan in parallel. And the fan popped.

Also if theres any material like video/article/website that could be of use, I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Different amps is fine. You want to find ones with the same volts. But if you can't, you can buy a circuit that converts the voltage. (Or build one, but I assume it's beyond your abilities right now)

Comment: Thanks! It probably is beyond my understanding of circuitry. But about converting the voltage. I looked into it after reading your answer. Lets say the rating for the peltier is 12v, and for the fan is 5v. Also given that I included a stepdown module for the 5v fan. For the power source or adapter. A 12v should be good right? Im not knowledgeable when it comes to that. But simply speaking. An adapter or power source that can output 12v should be fine for both? I hope im making sense.

Comment: I edited it. Can you confirm if i have the right idea?

Comment: Yes you do. And in case it's unclear, the 12v power source doesn't wire to the fan - the 12v power source wires to the step-down module's input, and the step-down module's 5v  output wires to the 5v fan.

Comment: Okay, does this makes sense? It could be horribly wrong (https://ibb.co/JjLZ2NK)   i hope my diagram is legible hahaha.

Comment: yup, makes sense. See, not too complicated, right? You just wire things in parallel to the same power source and they all get power from that source.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks my man! Appreciate it.